# Is it possible to play the original and HoF campaigns within Tribes of the East?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-5

I would like to play the official campaigns from both *HoMM V* and *HoMM V: Hammers of Fate* in the *Tribes of the East* expansion/standalone. The only advice I was able to find about accessing earlier campaigns was to run the corresponding version of the game (original for the first campaign, *HoF* for the second one). However, I'm curious what the gameplay would be like with *TotE* patches and additions.

So, is there a way to find out?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a really easy unofficial add-on made to integrate the H5/HoF campaigns in TotE here: http://www.heroes-fr.com/pages_en/original_campaigns.php

All you need to do is download Campaign and Text files (plus Cutscenes and Dialog if you want them) and put them in your ToE UserMODs folder. No ToE files need to be changed, patched or overwritten. More detailed instructions are on the link above.

The standalone format they released the expansions in really annoyed me too. Just remember when playing the old campaigns, the AI is equally capable of using the new creatures and everything else!

Comment: Website is down.. Any other way to acquire them?

Comment: Found it here, packaged with unofficial AI patch: https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/forums/showthread.php?611-The-HoMM5-Content-Combo-Pack-from-Good-to-Great-in-a-single-490MB-download&s=fda235bae882e7f0f8b1005aeb216526